# IObservable<T>.ToTask<T> method returns Task awaiting activation

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

Why does `task` await forever?:

```
var task = Observable
    .FromEventPattern<MessageResponseEventArgs>(communicator, "PushMessageRecieved")
    .Where(i => i.EventArgs.GetRequestFromReceivedMessage().Name == requestName)
    .Select(i => i.EventArgs)
    .RunAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None)
    .ToTask();

task.Wait();
```

I know `"PushMessageRecieved"` is fired; I can set a break point on the Select lambda and hit it. But `task.Wait()` never moves.

**Better Update:** `FirstAsync()` is what I am looking for:

```
    public static Task<MessageResponseEventArgs> HandlePushMessageRecievedAsync(this ICommunicator communicator, RequestName requestName)
    {
        if (communicator == null) return Task.FromResult<MessageResponseEventArgs>(null);

        var observable = GetCommunicatorObservableForPushMessageReceived(communicator);
        return observable
            .Where(i => i.GetRequestFromReceivedMessage().Name == requestName)
            .Select(i => i)
            .FirstAsync()
            .ToTask();
    }
```

where `GetCommunicatorObservableForPushMessageReceived()` is:

```
    static IObservable<MessageResponseEventArgs> GetCommunicatorObservableForPushMessageReceived(ICommunicator communicator)
    {
        if (communicatorObservableForPushMessageReceived == null)
        {
            communicatorObservableForPushMessageReceived = Observable
                .FromEventPattern<MessageResponseEventArgs>(communicator, "PushMessageRecieved")
                .Where(i => !IsPreviousMessage(i.EventArgs.GetRequestFromReceivedMessage().EventId))
                .Select(i => i.EventArgs);
        }

        return communicatorObservableForPushMessageReceived;
    }
```

*Update:* what is somewhat horrific is this (but it works):

```
public static Task<MessageResponseEventArgs> HandlePushMessageRecievedAsync(this ICommunicator communicator, RequestName requestName)
{
    if (communicator == null) return Task.FromResult<MessageResponseEventArgs>(null);

    var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<MessageResponseEventArgs>();

    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<MessageResponseEventArgs>(communicator, "PushMessageRecieved")
        .Where(i => i.EventArgs.GetRequestFromReceivedMessage().Name == requestName)
        .Select(i => i.EventArgs)
        .ToEvent().OnNext += (args) =>
        {
            if (args.Response.Errors != null && args.Response.Errors.Any())
            {
                completionSource.TrySetException(args.Response.Errors.Select(j => new Exception(j.ErrorMessage)));
            }
            else
            {
                completionSource.TrySetResult(args);
            }
        };

    return completionSource.Task;
}
```

Comment: Does the `Name` property match `requestName`?

Comment: @Lee: If it hits the `Select` lambda, as the OP says, then yes, it must match the Where clause.

Comment: Shouldn't ToTask occur before RunAsync?

Comment: @travis-j `RunAsync` returns `AsyncSubject<TSource>`

Comment: @james-world, the response from brandon may help, his criticisms function

Comment: FWIW @JamesWorld makes good points.  `ToTask` is really only fit for the purpose of integrating new Rx code with existing Task-based code.  If you are not trying to integrate your new Rx event with existing Task code you are better off not calling `ToTask`.  You can still do all the task-like things with Rx (Wait, await, continuations) only better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both `RunAsync` and `ToTask` yield *the very last value* in the observable.  Thus no value will be produced until the observable *completes*.  But observables created with `FromEventPattern` do not usually complete.  You need to force them to complete with something like `Take` or `Until`.

I'll also note that `RunAsync` and `ToTask` are essentially redundant and there isn't need to do both.

In your case, I'll assume you are really interested in the *first* value that makes it through your filter:

```
var task = Observable
    .FromEventPattern<MessageResponseEventArgs>(communicator, "PushMessageRecieved")
    .FirstAsync(i => i.EventArgs.GetRequestFromReceivedMessage().Name == requestName)
    .Select(i => i.EventArgs)
    .ToTask();

task.Wait();
```

Comment: Much appreciation! This works: `Select(i => i).Take(1).ToTask()`

Comment: This is even better: `Select(i => i).FirstAsync().ToTask()`

Comment: Why do you keep adding `Select(i=>i)`?  That serves no purpose.

Comment: @Brandon This is not my code, but I often add `select(x => x)` to my code while debugging. It lets me add breakpoints, and see what values are showing up. In this example Task is never returning, so I added the select to make sure that some value is at least getting this far. These are removed.

Answer (score 3):

The handlers for the `PushMessageRecieved` event that you are observing need to be run on the UI thread, in the current synchronization context.  You're blocking the UI thread (which represents the current context) while you wait for this task.  The task can't finish because you're waiting on it, you'll never finish waiting on it because it can't run.  Deadlock.

You shouldn't be synchronously blocking on the task but rather asynchronously executing code as a continuation of that task.

Comment: I appreciate what you are saying but will have to apply this advice to the case of a unit test: no UI thread.

Comment: @rasx First off, you should be sure that there is no synchronization context in your unit test; there may well be one.  And if there isn't **then there should be** because otherwise you're not properly emulating your real environment.