# Convert `IObservable<T>` to `IEnumerable<Task<T>>`?

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive

I have a couple of asynchronous APIs that use callbacks or events instead of `async`. I successfully used `TaskCompletionSource` to wrap them [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879967/best-way-to-convert-callback-based-async-method-to-awaitable-task).

Now, I would like to use an API that returns `IObservable<T>` and yields multiple objects. I read about Rx for .NET, which seems the way to go. However, I'm hesitant to include another dependency and another new paradigm, since I'm already using a lot of things that are new for me in this app (like XAML, MVVM, C#'s async/await).

Is there any way to wrap `IObservable<T>` analogously to how you wrap a single callback API? I would like to call the API as such:

```
foreach (var t in GetMultipleInstancesAsync()) {
    var res = await t;
    Console.WriteLine("Received item:", res);
}
```

Comment: If you're using C# 8 you could use another *new* thing called [IAsyncEnumerable](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/01/09/iasyncenumerable-in-c-8/) otherwise you could use [an rx observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049931/making-an-iobservablet-that-uses-async-await-return-completed-tasks-in-origina)

Comment: @Fabjan yeah it seems `IAsyncEnumberable` is `IEnumerable<Task>` in spirit. It lets you get rid of the temporary `await t` in favor of `await foreach (...)`. I just have to figure out how to transform the `IObservable`. Maybe there is an extension method somewhere.

Comment: @jdm you can find the `ToAsyncEnumerable` extension method in the [`System.Linq.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) package.

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused about the direction you're trying to go here. Can you please provide a [mcve]? Please include your API calls and how you're wrapping them and also the shell of the method that you're wanting to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If the observable emits multiple values, you can convert them to `Task<T>` and then add them to any `IEnumerable` structure.

Check [IObservable ToTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254964/iobservablet-totaskt-method-returns-task-awaiting-activation). As discussed here, the observable must complete before awaiting otherwise more values might come over.

[This guide here might do the trick for you too](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/flaviencharlon/2012/08/06/taskt-vs-iobservablet-when-to-use-what/)

```
public static Task<IList<T>> BufferAllAsync<T>(this IObservable<T> observable)
{
    List<T> result = new List<T>();
    object gate = new object();
    TaskCompletionSource<IList<T>> finalTask = new TaskCompletionSource<IList<T>>();

    observable.Subscribe(
        value =>
        {
            lock (gate)
            {
                result.Add(value);
            }
        },
        exception => finalTask.TrySetException(exception),
        () => finalTask.SetResult(result.AsReadOnly())
    );

    return finalTask.Task;
}
```

Comment: This method is equivalent to the combination of the methods `ToList` and `ToTask` from the [System.Reactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/) library. The `ToList` transforms an `IObservable<T>` to an `IObservable<IList<T>>`, and then the `ToTask` transforms this to a `Task<IList<T>>`.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to use Rx then you can use your returning list:

```
GetMultipleInstancesAsync().ToObservable().Subscribe(...);
```

You can subscribe the OnCompleted/OnError handler.

Also you can wrap it a task list:

```
var result = await Task.WhenAll(GetMultipleInstancesAsync().ToArray());
```

So you got an array of your results and you are done.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually looking for the opposite. I already have `IObservable`, and want the opposite of `ToObservable()`. Also, I don't want to wait for every `Task` to complete (`WhenAll`), I want to work on them as they come in.

Comment: Then simply subscribe to your observable. 
GetMultipleInstancesAsync().Subscribe(...);